# How to optimize the locations of todonote and tracking changes when the margin is 1cm

Tags: todonotes, changes

I am using packages todonote and changes, but they are barely to be seen as I have a template with a very small margin. Is there any way to make these notes below the text?
Thank you

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\definechangesauthor{Rev1}
\definechangesauthor{Rev2}
\todo[inline]{Reviewer 1 suggestion: Add more details to the experimental setup.}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5] In this paper, we present \added[id=Rev1,comment={Added more details to the experimental setup.}]{an improved experimental setup}
for our study.

\section{Methodology}
We conducted a \deleted[id=Rev1,comment={Removed redundant information.}]{comprehensive literature review} to gather data.\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Results}
The \replaced[id=Rev2,comment={Reworded for clarity.}]{result}{outcome} is consistent with our expectations.

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you check the todonotes documentation?

Comment: You ask for the `inline` option? You can also set page  5cm wider and then a  margin of 6cm do the text area remain unchanged.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I just found inline can work, but it won't work for package changes, like ```\added```

Comment: @Fran Thank you, but how to change the location for ```\added```

Comment: `\setuptodonotes{inline}`